# Django amazon s3 SuspiciousOperation

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

So when i try accessing a certain image on S3 from my browser everything works fine. But when python is doing it i get a `SuspiciousOperation` error. 
My static folder is public on S3 so i really have no idea where this is coming from.

```
Publication.objects.get(id=4039).cover.url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 64, in _get_url
    return self.storage.url(self.name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queued_storage/backends.py", line 291, in url
    return self.get_storage(name).url(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queued_storage/backends.py", line 115, in get_storage
    elif cache_result is None and self.remote.exists(name):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 410, in exists
    name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 341, in _normalize_name
    name)
SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to 'http:/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xpto/static/images/default-image.png' denied.
```

My settings:

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True  # use http instead of https
S3_URL = 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/%s' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_ROOT
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + '/' + MEDIA_ROOT
```

For now i can work around it, but that is not a long term solution. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Danigosa's answer in this thread is the answer:
[django-storages and amazon s3 - suspiciousoperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535123/django-storages-and-amazon-s3-suspiciousoperation)

Create a special storage class as outlined in this post:
[Using Amazon S3 to store your Django sites static and media files](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/).

Then override `_normalize_name` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):

    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

    def _clean_name(self, name):
        return name

    def _normalize_name(self, name):
        if not name.endswith('/'):
            name += "/"

        name = self.location + name
        return name


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):

    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION

    def _clean_name(self, name):
        return name

    def _normalize_name(self, name):
        if not name.endswith('/'):
            name += "/"

        name = self.location + name
        return name
```

Finally - (on Python 3 at least) DON'T use

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

in your templates.

Stick with:

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `name  = self.location + name` instead `name += self.location`

Comment: Right, the accepted answer has other issue and must be updated since `name += self.location` results to incorrectly joined path, and should be `name  = self.location + name` instead as suggested by @Pythonist.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. Tried all the available solutions. Realised that the issue was with the '/' that I had added while calling static files. Like this, "{% static '/path/to/static/file' %}", changed this to "{% static 'path/to/static/file' %}"