# images not getting displayed from amazon s3 bucket for django project

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

These are my s3 configuration.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'doctocliq.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'doctocliq.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'doctocliq'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Uploaded all the static files to the bucket with collectstatic command, except images all the other static files are working, on local server there is no issue also. The site link is http://doctocliq-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/. Hope some body can help me, thank you.

Comment: Aren't you missing region in S3_URL and MEDIA_URL?

Answer (score 0):

The S3_URl should be:

```
//s3-${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/% AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

As there is no region mentioned in the URL the object is not getting located. This is needed especially when the bucket is NOT in N. Virginia region.

Also, refer for SuspiciousOperation:

["Suspicious Operation" calling static files from Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529912/suspicious-operation-calling-static-files-from-amazon-s3)

[Django amazon s3 SuspiciousOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456420/django-amazon-s3-suspiciousoperation)

Comment: i have added as you mentioned, but didn't make any difference.

Comment: Is it adding the aws region in image url?

Comment: this error is only for some images, some them are visible, so when i change the debug to true, the error message is SuspiciousOperation at /registrar-doctor/
Attempted access to '/images/backgrounds/doctablet.png' denied.